# Running lapply on list in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am new to R, and am trying to use aRpsDCA to create a function to estimate decline parameters for an oil or gas well by history-matching.  I get it to work fine on a single well, but am having difficulties applying the formula to a large .csv file containing several wells (The dataset has a well identifier, cumulative months, and then rate at that month for all the wells, and they all have differing cumulative months).  I am trying to use lapply but so far am having errors.

I won't go through all of the function, but it takes two variables (q, t), or function(q,t).  The function is called h2e.fnc.  Here is what I am trying to use to get it to run over the entire list, but it's not working.

```
declAll <- lapply(hynsvl$API, h2e.fnc(hynsvl$q, hynsvl$t))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'h2e.fnc(hynsvl$q, hynsvl$t)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

$API is the well identifier, and then q and t are rate and time inputs into the function.

Any suggestions on how I would properly run this to get the function to calculate for all of the wells individually?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a reproducible example including test data to troubleshoot the code. For reference see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply to call  for all rows in your dataframe

```
twoarg <- function(a,b)
{
   a + b
}
l1 <- c(1:100)
l2 <- c(100:1)

df <- data.frame(l1,l2)

apply(df,1,function(x) twoarg(x["l1"],x["l2"])) # 1 all rows , 2 all columns
```